# bootstrap navbar with company logo at the top

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a angular 2 application using bootstrap. I want to have a navbar on my application so that app menu looks like [image]

When viewed from smaller devices it should look as follows :
[image]

I have used following code in my html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">COMPANY LOGO</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
            <ul *ngFor="let menu of menus;let first = first;" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a (click)="menuClicked(menu.categoryId)"
                       href='#/{{menu.categoryName}}'
                       style="color: #fff;font-size: 16px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;">
                        {{menu.categoryName}}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Which gives me following output :

[image]

Can someone guide how to achieve desired output?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/zrrhmv1u/1/  make it full screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mandar Patil, I've linked to a [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/rf7qIXArh6) that should meet your requirements.

For the brand on the collapsed navigation menu, you can just use bootstraps `visible` and `hidden` utility classes, and specify the appropriate breakpoints.

HTML

```
<div class="container hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">COMPANY LOGO</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
       <div class="navbar-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#" style="color: white;">COMPANY LOGO</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try For this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <div class="col-md-12 clearfix">
      <div class="row"> 
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 clearfix"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```